# Como manipular Front de outra Janela com JS

Tags: javascript

Já pesquisei até cansar... o que eu gostaria de fazer era algo do tipo:

```
var janela = window.open(
    "https://www.google.com/", 
    "_blank"
);
var pesquisa = janela.document.getElementById("lst-ib");
pesquisa.value = "string que quero no input";
```

mas não funciona, coloquei:

```
var janela = window.open(
    "https://www.google.com/", 
    "_blank"
);
var pesquisa = janela.document.getElementById("lst-ib");
console.log(pesquisa);
```

imprimiu **null**

### POR QUE?

alguem me ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa esperar que a janela seja carregada para que o elemento esteja disponível e você possa alterar. Pode fazer isso tratando o evento `onload`:

```
var janela = window.open(
    "https://www.google.com/", 
    "_blank"
);
janela.onload = function(){
    var pesquisa = janela.document.getElementById("lst-ib");
    pesquisa.value = "string que quero no input";
}
```

Se você estiver testando local da sua máquina provavelmente vai tomar um erro de permissão de segurança, por exemplo "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT".

Comment: funcionou vlw :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pesquisa = "string que quero no input";
    var janela = window.open(
        "https://www.google.com/?q=" + pesquisa, 
        "_blank"
    );
```

Veja se isso ajuda, o texto que colocar em pesquisa vai entrar como um GET no dominio do google e com o campo preenchido, mas não é feito a pesquisa é preciso selecionar buscar.